# А как сравнить два потока типа istringstream?

Tags: c++

Имеются два потока типа istringstream. Как их сравнить?

Comment: по какому критерию хотите, так и сравнивайте, например: (stream1.str().length() < stream2.str().length())

Comment: Смотря что вы понимаете под сравнением. На равенство, на отношение "меньше", на равенство содержимого etc etc...

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream a, b;
    a.str() == b.str();
}
```

Comment: ЗА ЧТО МИНУСУЮТ?!?!?!??!!